# So, I have this differential equation problem to solve but only using real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

The problem is:

Given f such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(x) = [f(x)]^3$, show that $f(x) = 0\; \forall x \in [0,\infty)$. I wanted to use Cauchy-Picard, but my sister said it should be solved with basic real analysis only. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Partial solution, if the domain of $f$ were extended (somewhat inspired by the "conversation of energy" type of argument): consider $g(x) := [f(x)]^4$.  Then $g'(x) = 4 [f(x)]^3 f'(x) = 4 [f(x)]^6 \ge 0$.  Therefore, for $x < 0$, $g(x) \le 0$; but also, since $g$ is a square, $g(x) \ge 0$.  Thus, $g(x) \equiv 0$ for $x < 0$, which implies $f(x) \equiv 0$ for $x < 0$.

Comment: Another partial solution: $f'(0)=0, \quad f''(0)=3f(0)^2f'(0)=0, \quad f'''(0)=0$, etc. Therefore if $f$ is real-analytic it must be $f\equiv 0$. This is not a complete solution, because there are functions $g(x)\not \equiv 0$ with $g^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: $y'=y^3$ separate variables $\dfrac{dy}{y^3}=dx$ integrate both sides $-\dfrac{1}{2y^2}=x+C$ the initial condition is incompatible with this solution, therefore the only solution is $f(x)=0$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x_0$ be the suppremum of the $x$ such that $f(t)=0$ for $t\in[0,x]$.

If $x_0$ is finite:

Let $1>a>0$ be such that $|f(x)|<1/M$ for your favorite $M>1$ on $[x_0,x_0+a]$.

Then $|f(x)|=\left|\int_{x_0}^{x}f'(t)dt\right|=\left|\int_{x_0}^{x}f^3(t)dt\right|\leq 1/M^3$ for $x\in[x_0,x_0+a]$.

Repeating the same argument, using the new found bound $1/M^3$ instead of $1/M$ and so on, we get that $|f(x)|<1/M^{3^{n}}$ for all $n$, on $x\in[x_0,x_0+a]$. Therefore $f(x)=0$ for $x\in[x_0,x_0+a]$.

Therefore $x_0$ is not finite.

Comment: This is, of course, the same fixed point business as the uniqueness and existence proof.

Comment: The t in [0,t] should be a x. I can't suggest an edit because edits have to be six characters long.

Comment: @Levi Haunschmid: Just add "more characters required".

Answer (score 0):

Formally, this is a separable equation:
$$
{df \over dx} = f(x)^3,
$$
so:
$$
dx = {df \over f^3}.
$$
However, this would be valid only in a neighborhood of a state where $f(x) \neq 0$.  Since, by contrast, $f(0) = 0$, direct inspection shows that $f(x) \equiv 0$ is a solution.  To see that it is unique, consider the subsets of the $f$-axis invariant under the flow of the vector field $v(f) = f^{3}$.  There are only three such subsets: the strictly positive semiaxis $f>0$, the strictly negative semiaxis $f<0$, and the point $f=0$.  Since a solution to the ODE must be contained in one of the subsets, it follows that it must lie in $\{0\}$; i.e., $f \equiv 0$.

Source: [https://books.google.com/books?id=JUoyqlW7PZgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=ordinary+differential+equations&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjWiomptPXUAhXEyT4KHWWMAvgQ6AEIKzAA#v=onepage&q=ordinary%20differential%20equations&f=false]

Comment: That works for *nonzero* solutions, but the question was about $f(0)=0$.

Comment: I'll correct my answer, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's still not right. It's obvious that $f(x)=0$ is *a* solution, but the question is how to show that it's the *only* solution (without invoking the Picard uniqueness theorem)...

Comment: Ok, I corrected further, but used some advanced stuff.  Its advantage is that it is geometric: one can literally compute and sketch the $v$-invariant sets in question.

Comment: Really sorry to be a pain, but when you start talking about the flow, you are already implicitly assuming the uniqueness theorem. (Cf. the section **A Counterexample** on p. 36 of Arnold's book that you linked to.)

Comment: Good point.  Well, if I understand correctly, uniqueness can be shown on each open semiaxis by a method other than Picard's theorem; namely, by the local rectification theorem.  This suffices: if any solution $f(x)$ has a point in an open semiaxis, then it is unique.  The only solution that has no points in either semiaxis is $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: And, don't be sorry,--I benefit from this discussion, so thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could "unfold" the proof of Cauchy-Picard, in order to get a basic real analysis proof which would go something like this:

Since $f$ is differentiable, $f$ is continuous, so choose $\delta > 0$ such that $\delta \le 1$, and $|f(x)| < \frac{1}{2}$ whenever $|x| < \delta$.  Let $A := \sup \{ |f(x)| : x \in [0, \delta] \}$.  Then for $x \in [0, \delta]$, $f(x) = \int_0^x [f(t)]^3 \, dt$, so
$$|f(x)| \le \int_0^x |f(t)|^3 \, dt \le x A^3.$$
Therefore, $A \le \delta A^3 \le A^3$, which together with the fact that $0 \le A \le \frac{1}{2}$ implies that $A = 0$.

Therefore, we have shown that $f(x) \equiv 0$ for $x \in [0, \delta]$, for some $\delta > 0$.  From here, the proof concludes using the translation invariance of the differential equation, along with a connectedness type of argument.

Answer (score 0):

Let $a=\min\left(1,\sup\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^+: |f(x)|\leq 1\right\}\right)$.

Let us define $g(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{rcl} f(x) &\text{if} & x\in\left[0,\frac{a}{2}\right]\\ f(a-x)&\text{if}& x\in\left[\frac{a}{2},1\right]\end{array}\right.$

By applying [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) to $g(x)$ we get:
$$\int_{0}^{a}g(x)^2\,dx \leq \frac{a^2}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{a}g'(x)^2\,dx \leq \frac{a^2}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{a} g(x)^6\,dx\leq \frac{a^2}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{a}g(x)^2\,dx $$
hence $g(x)\equiv 0$ on $[0,a]$ and $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $\left[0,\frac{a}{2}\right]$.
 By shifting and repeating the same argument we get $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$.