# Function limiting its own derivative implies implies null function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a continuous differentiable function in $\mathbb{R}$. If $f(0)=0$ and $|f'(x)|\leq|f(x)|,\;\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $f$ is the null function.

Following @DougM's idea, I think I figured it out:
Consider $f$ restricted to the interval $[0,1]$. Then, by Weirstrass theorem there exists $x_1,x_2 \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x_1)\leq f(x)\leq f(x_2),\;\forall x \in [0,1]$. Suppose, WLOG, that $|f(x_1)|\geq|f(x_2)|$. Note that this implies $|f(x_1)|\geq |f(x)|,\; \forall x \in [0,1]$.
If $x_1=0$, then $f(x)=0, \forall x \in [0,1]$.
Suppose $x_1\neq0$. Then, by the mean value theorem, there exists $c \in (0,1)$ such that: 
\begin{align}
f(x_1)-f(0)&=f'(c)(x_1-0)\\
|f(x_1)|&=|f'(c)||x_1|\\
|f(x_1)|&\leq|f'(c)|
\end{align}
But then $|f(c)|\geq|f'(c)|\geq|f(x_1)|$.
As $c\in(0,1)\subset[0,1]$, by the men value theorem there exists $d\in(0,c)\subset[0,1]$ such that:
\begin{align}
f(c)-f(0)&=f'(d)(c-0)\\
|f(c)|&=|f'(d)||c|\\
|f(c)|&<|f'(d)|
\end{align}
But then $|f(d)|\geq|f'(d)|>|f(c)\geq |f(x_1)|$, a contradiction. since $|f(x_1)|\geq |f(x),\; \forall x\in [0,1]$.
Therefore $x_1=0$.
From there you can just follow inductively to prove $f(x)=0$ for all positives, and the analogous proof for the negatives.
Using the MVT twice is kinda weird, wonder if there's a way not to use it like that.

Comment: Well, what do you think about the problem?

Comment: You can use the same idea as [this proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2347742/458675). In the spot where $f'$ got replaced by $f^3$ replace it with $f$ instead and put an inequality instead of an equality.

Comment: Do you know the mean value theorem, an can you think about how it might apply here.

Comment: @DougM yes, I do know it, Been trying to use it with little success.

Comment: @Bettybel I'm not supposed to use integrals in this exercise though...

Comment: This is an interesting question, but the original poster should add his/her attempts in order to prevent downvotes/closing.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Edited it!

Comment: @anomaly Gave it a shot, wonder if it's correct though

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that $f'(x)$ is continuous and $|f'(x)|\le|f(x)|$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1645388/let-f-mathbbr-rightarrow-mathbbr-be-a-function-such-that-fx-is-conti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVT

if $f(x)$ is continuous in $[a,b]$ and differentiable in $(a,b)$ there exists a $c \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(c) = \frac {f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$

How can we apply that

$\exists q\in [0,1]: \forall x\in [0,1], |f(q)|\ge |f(x)|$ (extreme value theorem)

i.e. let $|f(q)|$ be the maximal value of $|f(x)|$ when $x$ is in $[0,1]$

$|f'(x)|\le |f(q)|$ for all $x \in [0,1]$

$|f(q)| \ge |f'(q)| \ge |\frac {f(q)}{q}|\\
q|f(q)|\ge |f(q)|$

and since $q<1, |f(q)| = 0.$

Prove by induction.  Use the identical argument so show that if $f(x) = 0$  for all $x \in [0,n]$ then $ \forall x \in [0,n+1], f(x) = 0$

And similarly, if $\forall x \in [-n,0], f(x) = 0$ then $\forall x \in [-n-1,0], f(x) = 0$

Comment: I think there are few mistakes in this. Why would $a<1$ ? Where is the $c$ in your mvt application ? The proof seems fine to me once those are clarified.

Comment: perhaps my redundant use of the letter $a$ was confusing

Comment: I still dont get why $q<1$

Comment: @DougM I edited the question following your answer, is it correct?

Answer (score 1):

Following Bettybel's hint: let $x_0$ be the supremum of $t\in\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(x)=0$ on $[0,t]$.
Assume that $x_0$ is finite, let $I=\left[x_0,x_0+\frac{1}{2}\right]$ and let $M=\max_{x\in I}|f(x)|$.
 
For any $x\in I$ we have
$$ f(x) = f(x_0)+\int_{x_0}^{x}f'(\xi)\,d\xi  $$
from which
$$ |f(x)|\leq (x-x_0) M \leq \frac{M}{2} $$
and $M=0$, contradicting $x_0=\sup\left\{t\in\mathbb{R}^+:\forall x\in[0,t],\, f(x)=0\right\}.$
It follows that $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and by replacing $f(x)$ with $f(-x)$ we also have $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}^-$.

---

As an alternative, we may define $g(x)$ as $f(x)$ on $[0,1]$ and as $f(2-x)$ on $[1,2]$, then apply [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions) to $g(x)$:

$$ \int_{0}^{2}g(x)^2\,dx \leq \frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{2}g'(x)^2\,dx \leq \frac{4}{\pi^2}\int_{0}^{2}g(x)^2\,dx $$
implies $g(x)\equiv 0$ on $[0,2]$, hence $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $[0,1]$. By shifting and repeating the same argument, $f(x)\equiv 0$ on $\mathbb{R}$.

---

We do not need the continuity of $f'$, and indeed $f\in H^{1}_{\text{loc}}$ is enough to prove the claim with the last approach.

Comment: How do you get $M=0$?

Comment: @BAI: $$ M=\max_{x\in I}|f(x)|\leq \max_{x\in I}\frac{M}{2}\leq \frac{M}{2}$$ implies $M=0$.

Comment: I see, thanks (+1)